# #define conflict with my data type and enumerator element

Tags: c++, x11

My data type called "Bool" which is inside a namespace conflicts with #define Bool int which is defined in some Xlib header file. Also, the same thing happens when I put an element called "None" inside any enumerator, because of the definition #define None 0L.
I've tried to use #undef Bool in multiple files, but it just turned into a mess.
Should I rename the data type to something like "Boolean" and stop using "None" for good?

Comment: In general you really should avoid name shadowing standard type names, classes, etc. You will run into way more trouble than is worth dealing with.

Comment: I'm making it cross-platform. It should work for older consoles as well.

Comment: Also, what about the case where I'm using the name "None" for any enumerator element?

Comment: Is there some reason Xlib uses `#define Bool int` and not `typedef int Bool`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing Xlib programming, you will want to avoid redefining `Bool`, `True`, `False` and `None` (as well as `XID` and `XPointer` and `Status`) to avoid conflicts with the `#define` and `typedef` values in the Xlib headers.

Since you're using C++11, you should either use the Xlib `Bool` or use the standard C++ `bool` in your code.  Your life will be easier if you can isolate the Xlib `#include` files to as few compilation units (source files) as possible and use the standard C++ `bool` everywhere else.

Comment: Okey, I see your point. But I'm actually porting my library from Win32 where it worked perfectly and I would like to keep using the current design. I'm actually just using the Xlib files in three of my files, window, graphic-creation and an OpenGL header file.